# Listing business days between two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, series

Rather than counting, I need the actual list of business days between begin and end date columns in my dataframe so I can loop through them to add rows for another issue.

Here's what I'm looking for (created the 'list bd' column manually to show what I would like the output to be):

```
 begin date end date    list bd
2020-11-02  2020-11-04  ['2020-11-02', '2020-11-03', '2020-11-04']
2020-11-03  2020-11-06  ['2020-11-03', '2020-11-04', '2020-11-05', '2020-11-06']
2020-11-05  2020-11-10  ['2020-11-05', '2020-11-06', '2020-11-09', '2020-11-10']
```

What I've tried:

```
df['list_bd'] = pd.bdate_range(df['begin date'], df['end date']).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `zip` the columns `begin date` and `end date` and use `bdate_range` inside a list comprehension:

```
df['list bd'] = [pd.bdate_range(*v).astype(str).tolist() for v in zip(df['begin date'], df['end date'])]
```

---

```
  begin date   end date                                           list bd
0 2020-11-02 2020-11-04              [2020-11-02, 2020-11-03, 2020-11-04]
1 2020-11-03 2020-11-06  [2020-11-03, 2020-11-04, 2020-11-05, 2020-11-06]
2 2020-11-05 2020-11-10  [2020-11-05, 2020-11-06, 2020-11-09, 2020-11-10]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much.